# Windows Forms Video Capture to pictureBox Without Distortion

Tags: c#, winforms, video-capture

I am trying to get normal video output from my camera inside of my windows forms application. Since it was cropping the video output otherwise I am resizing it. I made the picture box size 640 to 360 so it should be half of my 1280 to 720 built-in camera. However, the image output is stretched horizontally.
the code that I am resizing is this one:

```
Bitmap unresized = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
Bitmap newFrame = new Bitmap(unresized, 640, 360);
```

```
pictureBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = newFrame;
                }));
```

How can I make it so that it does the conversion without distorting the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should likely just change the SizeMode of your picturebox:

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

This should fit the image to your picture box, while maintaining the aspect ratio. There should be no need to manually resize an image.